# Is there a way to run a jenkins container on docker on a raspberry pi4 running raspbian?

Tags: docker, jenkins, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi4 running raspbian plus docker. I am trying to run a jenkins container but it fails with this error:
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
I have read somewhere that it might be because raspbian is 32bits and that jenkins image is a 64bits one. Is there a 32bits image of jenkins?

Comment: You don't only need a 32 bit image, you need a 32 bit ARM image. I don't know whether jenkins is available for ARM CPUs.

Comment: Thanks! Jenkins is available for ARM but there are no docker images for it, si I created my own. It's working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @CristhianZevallos would you share that image with the rest of the community?